# How do I get my nav menu to transition when the activeRoute changes?

Tags: angular, routes, components, transition

I am currently refactoring a current site that I prototyped using the Angular framework versus my down and dirty coding.

The prototype has 3 states of location within the viewport.

1. On the parent/home page
2. On the child pages
3. On the grandchild pages

I have transitions set up to move the menu from one location to the next. In the prototype I just used a javascript function based on the class of the nav. Now I would like to port this site over to Angular, and harness the power of the framework to find the data state of the activated route to transition the menu.

I have attempted to capture the active route using a combination of functions, many from stack exchange and many from the Angular website without much luck.

I have attempted to bind the routeAnimations to the prepareRoute method, and I get an outlet undefined error.

I have attempted to check the url within the onInit method which always seems to return just '/' never anything else.

app/app.component.html

```
<app-menu></app-menu>

<main>
<router-outlet #outlet="outlet"></router-outlet>
</main>
```

app/app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path:'home', component: HomeComponent, 
    data: {state: 'hp',} 
  },
  {path:'listen', component: ListenComponent, 
    data: {state: 'nav',}
  },
  {path:'crew', component: CrewComponent, 
    data: {state: 'nav',} 
  },
  {path:'about', component: AboutComponent, 
    data: {state: 'nav',} 
  },
  {path:'contact', component: ContactComponent, 
    data: {state: 'nav',} 
  }
];
```

app/menu/menu.component.html

```
<nav [ngClass]="{'hp': active=='hp', 'nav':active == 'nav', 'nav-h': active== 'navh'}" [@routeAnimations]="active">
  <h2>Plot Your Course</h2>
  <ul>
    <li class="button-4" [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"><a [routerLink]="['/home']">Home</a></li>
    <li class="button-1" [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"><a [routerLink]="['/listen']">Listen</a></li>
    <li class="button-2" [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"><a [routerLink]="['/crew']">Crew</a></li>
    <li class="button-3" [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"><a [routerLink]="['/about']">About</a></li>
    <li class="button-4" [routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"><a [routerLink]="['/contact']">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

app/menu/menu.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.less'],
  animations: [ trigger('routeAnimations', [
    state('hp', style({
      left: '50%',
      top: '40%',
      width: '610px'
    })),
    state('nav', style({
      left: 0,
      paddingLeft: '30px',
      width: '330px'
    })),
    state('navh', style({
      top: 0,
      position: 'fixed'
    })),
    transition('hp <=> nav',[
      animate('.5s')
    ]),
    transition('nav <=> navh',[
      animate('.5s')
    ]),
    transition('navh <=> hp', [
      animate ('.5s')
    ])
  ])]
})

export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {
  public active: string = "";
  public url1: string = "";

  constructor( private router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.url1 = this.router.url;


    if (this.url1 == '/' || 'home'){
      this.active = 'hp';
      return this.active;
    }

    return this.url1;
  }

  checkActiveRoute(url1){
    switch (url1){
      case 'crew/*': 
        this.active='navh';
        return this.active;
      case 'listen' || 'crew' || 'about' || 'contact' :
        this.active='nav';
        return this.active;
      default:
        this.active='hp';
        return this.active;
    } 
  } 

  prepareRoute(outlet: RouterOutlet) {
    return outlet && outlet.activatedRouteData && outlet.activatedRouteData['state'];
  }
}
```

The outcome should behave like that shown on https://bloodypirateradio.com/

I am sure there is something simple that I am missing or overlooking, as I am relatively new to Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Hi add `routerLinkActive="your-custom-class"` you'll 'your-custom-class' to customize how active link will look, also add `[routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"` and when you'll navigate to `/feed` for example angular will apply this class and this options means if you navigate to `/feed/post` angular will delete this class so if you want to be active whatever link which start with `/feed` you can delete this option. Check the example bellow and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

```
<a
    class="nav-link"
    [routerLink]="['/feed']"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true }"
    routerLinkActive="active-nav-link"> 
       {{ 'PostsFeed' | translate }}
</a>
```

Comment: I'm using the ```[routerLinkActive]="['active-link']"``` in the ```<li>``` to hide the active button, however this doesn't really explain how to get the entire ```<nav>``` to transition from one location to another. I'm looking to hook into the route state object listed in the router to conditionally set the class and the ```[@routeAnimations]```